# Get Disabled/Hidden Relation Table Records using TYPO3 Repository Query

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-8.7.x

I've a requirement in my custom extension where there are records, lets say which are projects saved in table name: `tx_myextension_domain_model_projects` and which are categorized using custom category table `tx_myextension_domain_model_categories` the relation which is mapped in model is m:n and saved in mm table `tx_myextension_category_record_mm`.

**This is the TCA mapping for the category field:**

```
products_category' => [
    'exclude' => true,
    'label' => 'Category Label',
    'config' => [
        'type' => 'select',
        'renderType' => 'selectTree',
        'foreign_table' => 'tx_myextension_domain_model_categories',
        'foreign_table_where' => 'ORDER BY tx_myextension_domain_model_categories.sorting',
        'MM' => 'tx_myextension_category_record_mm',
        'MM_match_fields' => [
            'tablenames' => 'tx_myextension_domain_model_projects',
        ],
        'MM_opposite_field' => 'items',
        'size' => 20,
        'treeConfig' => [
            'parentField' => 'parent',
            'appearance' => [
                'showHeader' => true,
                'expandAll' => true,
                'maxLevels' => 99,
            ],
        ],
    ],

],
```

So in one of my use cases I need to get the projects which are categorized with disabled and active categories.

**For example this is the categories :**

```
categories = [
    A => [
        A1 => [
            A1.2
        ]
        A2 => [
            A2.2
        ]
    ],
    B => [
        B1 => [
            B1.2
        ]
    ],

];
```

Lets say `A1` is disabled/hidden record and I want to get the projects which are assigned to `A1` and its child `A1.2`. Is there any possibilities to get the project records using TYPO3 Repository query.

**Note:** I couldn't disable the enable fields using                  `$querySettings->setIgnoreEnableFields(true);` because I don't want to disable it for the entire repository of category and also I need to disable it from the Project repository while query the project records. I hope my question is clear. Please let me know the solution for this.

**Solution Currently I choosed:** I used TYPO3 Connection Pool Query instead of repository query.

Comment: TYPO3 has some default that are applied to a query directly. I think you might have to configure the repository settings to change those defaults. You can find an overview here (old! maybe there is  better resource somewhere): https://wiki.typo3.org/Default_Orderings_and_Query_Settings_in_Repository. Once the defaults are "turned off", you can implement a query over "hidden" again in your own query.

Comment: Also, maybe the Restriction Builder is of help: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ApiOverview/Database/RestrictionBuilder/Index.html#database-restriction-builder.

Answer (score 0):

Why isnt $query->getQuerySettings()->setIgnoreEnableFields(true); an option for you? You can build the query exactly the way you need it like you would do with the Connection Pool.